# Get Params from ajax response Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I created a new action in the "contributions" controller like this

```
def newitem
    @Item = Item.new(:description => params[:description], :type_id => params[:type])
    if @Item.save
     #Magic supposed to happen here
   end
  end
```

So in this action I create a new "Item" and what I want to achieve is to get the id from the created item in an AJAX response, so I can use it in the same view the "item" is created...

1st question, how do I send back from the controller the params of the created item?
2nd I know how to handle Ajax requests but how do I handle an Ajax response to the first request...

Perhaps I am over thinking the solution but just cant figure out how to do it. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to tackle this. The approaches explained below are for Rails 3.1

Call render directly in your method(this approach is helpful for a JSON API only approach. Since html rendering will be non-existant):

```
def newItem
    @Item = Item.create(:description => params[:description], :type_id => params[:type])
    render json: @Item
end
```

Use a respond_do block:

```
def newItem
  @Item = Item.create(:description => params[:description], :type_id => params[:type])

    respond_to do |format|
    if @Item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @Item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @Item, status: :created, location: @Item 
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @Item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Teach your controller the response formats you desire:

```
class ContributionsController < ApplicationController
  # Set response format json
  respond_to :json

  ...

  def newItem
    @Item = Item.create(:description => params[:description], :type_id => params[:type])
    respond_with @Item  #=> /views/contributions/new_item.json.erb
  end
```

Possible "gotcha"...

If you have validation failures on Item create you will not get the id back, nor will it report a failure (other than the http response code)

Add the following to your model. It'll include the validation failures in an errors hash within the json response

```
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

   ...

   # includes any validation errors in serializable responses 
   def serializable_hash( options = {} ) 
     options = { :methods => [:errors] }.merge( options ||= {} )
     super options
   end
```

There's always more than one way to skin a cat. I hope this helps